# I am trying to programmatically add images to a list/array and access them in a for each loop to change their source image

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have been trying to add images to an array and then access their properties to change their source image in a loop.

Detailed: I create a grid with a layout for each for each grid element, in that layout there is a GridImage, who's source folder is set to "ClosedFolder.png", when I click one of the layouts it should change the clicked layouts folder to "OpenFolder.png".

```
for (int eachCount = 0; eachCount <= MaxRows / MaxCols; eachCount++)
{
    Selectedrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(80, GridUnitType.Absolute) });
    for (int newCol = 0; newCol <= MaxCols; newCol++)
    {
        for (int newRow = 0; newRow <= MaxRows / MaxCols; newRow++)
        {
            if (folderIndex >= DirectoryArrayList.Count) { break; }
            var folder = DirectoryArrayList[folderIndex];
            var label = new Label()
            {
                Text = folder.Name,
                FontSize = 12,
                VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
            };
            var GridImage = new Image() { Source = "ClosedFolder.png", StyleId = "Image" };
            var GridTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            var Layout = new StackLayout() { StyleId = "StackContent" };
            var folderSelection = _mainFolder + "/" + folder.Name;
            GridTap.Tapped += async(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                FileHandler.CreateTextFiles(folderSelection, "File_" + FileID + ".txt");
                files = FolderOptions.AddFilesToList(folderSelection);
                lst.ItemsSource = files;
                //foreach (Image img in ImageList) I know this i incorrect, just an example of what I think!
                //{
                //    img.Source = "ClosedFolder.png";
                //}
                GridImage.Source = "OpenFolder.png"; // clicked layout gets its openfolder.png
            };
            Layout.Children.Add(label);
            Layout.Children.Add(GridImage);                            
            Layout.GestureRecognizers.Add(GridTap);
            Selectedrid.Children.Add(Layout, newCol, newRow);
            folderIndex += 1;
            FileID += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure on the declaration of the array and how to implement it.

Comment: What is your question?  You posted a bunch of code and told us what you wanted, but haven't actually asked a question beyond "can anyone help?".  Are you getting errors or exceptions?  What specifically is the code doing (or not doing) that you need help with?  If you are just trying to change a single image in a grid cell, this seems like an cumbersome approach.

Comment: Sorry for that, Thier are no erros, the code so far works fine, it was an exapmle with commented code to show what i think should happen... I want to change the current layout image ClosedFolder.png with OpenFolder.png, and then loop through the other images, see if they have an openfolder.png and change it back to closedfolder.png, I hope that is more clear? I understand that my code is not the most beutifull, I am trying to learn coding at the moment :-)

Comment: Are you building this Grid dynamically?  If so then I'd use a bindable layout instead, and then you can just manipulate the bound model instead of trying to directly access the UI.

Comment: @jason, yes I am building it dynamically, I am not 100% sure how i will do that, I have looked at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts)  here is how I initialize it at the moment...            InitializeComponent();
            var _GridFolders = new Grid(); _GridFolders = GridFolders;
            var _List = new ListView(); _List = ListFiles;
            BasicGridClass.BasicGrid(MaxCols, MaxRows, _GridFolders, _List);

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-bindable-layout/

Comment: @Jason, Thnx a lot for the page example, I will try the implementation and will let you know when I have done it.

Comment: @jason, It looks proper and the correct way to go about things, but this will take time for me to implicate it, so for now I resolved my problem for now by doing the following ...                         var ImageList = new List<Image> { };
                        ImageList.Add( GridImage );
                        for (var i = 0; i < ImageList.Count; i++)
                        {
                            var img = ImageList[i];
                            img.Source = "ClosedFolder.png";
                        } GridImage.Source = "OpenFolder.png"; I'll set as solved thnx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209469/discussion-between-mark-and-jason).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following into my BasicGrid method ...

```
 var GridImage = new Image() { Source = "ClosedFolder.png", StyleId = "Image" }; 
 var ImageList = new List<Image>{};
 ImageList.Add( GridImage );
 for (var i = 0; i < ImageList.Count; i++)
     {
         var img = ImageList[i];
         img.Source = "ClosedFolder.png";
     } GridImage.Source = "OpenFolder.png"
```

Just adding to say that Jason's information is the most likely direction I will go in, but as I am still learning it will take me time and I dint want to keep this open while I do that :-)

Comment: Can you please mark this answer which will help more people with same problem?